# Which version of GIMP should I install?

Tags: software-installation, gimp

I have linox & want to download  Gimp. Which version should I use?

Comment: What does Google Chrome, a web browser, have to do with the installation of an image editing application?

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you can install gimp by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Alternatively, open ubuntu software center, search for gimp and install it there.

This way, you will get Gimp version 2.8.10 (for ubuntu trusty and utopic). If you want a newer version (newest is 2.8.14), have a look at http://www.gimp.org/downloads/.

For additional information, look at [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

To get latest version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```